# Реализация интерфеса

Tags: typescript

как можно по другому (через класс) реализовать интерфейс, а так же что дает первая строка в интерфейсе? это просто интерфейс к функции ?

```
export interface ITest {
  (): string;
  name: string;
}
```

я сделал через функцию:

```
function d(): ITest {
  let v: ITest = (): string => "123";
  // v.name = "123";
  return v;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types

Этот интерфейс описывает функцию которая не принимает параметров и возвращает строку. Так же он говорит, что у функции есть имя.

Впрочем в JS у любой функции есть имя и когда мы объявили интерфейс

```
interface ITest {
  (): string;
};
```

то TS уже знает что это функция и автоматически применяет все методы и свойства функций. Например можно написать:

```
let f: ITest;
f.call(null)
```

потому что у функций есть метод `call`.

Так что любая функция без параметров возвращающая строку подходит под это описание.

```
interface ITest {
  (): string;
  name: string;
};

function a() { return 'ok'; }
const c = function() { return 'ok' };
const d = function e() { return 'ok' };
const b = () => 'ok';
const e = (s?: string) => s || 'ok';

function A(s: string) { return s };
function B() { return 42 };

declare function check(func :ITest): boolean;

// ok
check(a);
check(b);
check(c);
check(d);
// ok потому что в A можно не передавать параметры
check(e);

// not ok — у функции есть обязательный параметр
check(A);
// not ok — функция возвращает не строку
check(B);
// not ok — не функция
checK(42);
```

[примеры](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUIGczIN4BQyyAFAJQBcyOUoA5gNxHIhwC2EVN9TAvkwRgBXEAjDAA9iGRxy+ZFAhghUaQHIJAazUNkvAgik5kCZAF5kw0eKly8CpSvVa1epoZDGAJucsixktIQdg7Kqsga2m4GRrgARr5yZgB8ES7uscgoFiRYAPxcYLQgdGTmqVjIAD5VadoCVgFSyACCuYXFpfKKYdKV-IL+NtIAQiE9TsgALABM0QReEAgANnCKftaBJgAWS5okjcgUGNhglMhxEhLLEHAgAgD0D8haBrsI+3Bk7u-7cd9vPYkBAAhC-EheAFPF6aZCAfhBAHwggCEQBGAHhBAMIgyEA4iAo5CAJhBWshUQjAGwggF4QBHIMmAVhB4dTAAIg1MALCCABhA8SykYAZEHhLPpLNR1KR9MA0iCAj4kCAAgjQkASXBaZCAFAJkJjACIg6LJgC4QQBiIIAOEF1yGpgEEQLnIBGARhBAPIggHYQDnUwDcIJyycLAJwgPL5AqFYv2LShz1l8thyvVWr1lvxCOteL5gEkQFmCqm0k30hGa9HekgjP0sOUwpWJ5AhnW6y1igDSJFm3yAA)

Comment: Вот это `(): string;` описывает функцию которая не принимает параметров?

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов и возвращает строку. Да.

Comment: @AlexeyTen я могу этим интерфейсом расширить класс? как тогда нужно будет реализовать в классе `(): string;`?

Comment: Не понял вопрос

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц `let counter = 0; console.log(foo().counter); console.log(new foo().counter);
function foo() { const self = this || {}; self.counter = counter++; return self }`